# Comments not allowed at end of code in read only mode in Toad SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, toad

I've been using Toad as my SQL editor for a database that I have Read Only access to. Sometimes I'll comment out of line of code like 'ORDER BY Year' at the end of the code and it always causes an error.

```
SELECT *
FROM TableName
--Comment that causes an error
```

What is it about comments at the end of SQL statements that would cause an error when placed at the end, or is this just a TOAD quirk? Can comments there possibly modify the statement somehow?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: That's perfectly legal T-SQL so its a TOAD thing.

Comment: `Lookup Error - This command is not allowed in read only mode`
I felt like it was just a Toad thing, it just seems strange to call a comment a command as if it could do something, thanks!

Comment: As alex said this is perfectly fine T-SQL. I'm curios, if you change comment type from -- to /* does it work? so it would be /* this is a test */

Comment: Using `/*` generates the same error.

Comment: If you don't get anywhere here you may have success posting to the official Toad SQL Server forum. The dev team should hang out there and confirm any bug or explain why the behavior is so. http://www.toadworld.com/products/toad-for-sql-server